# Can't use Spring Initializr for 2.0.0 / Jackson 2.9.4

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jackson

Spring Noob here. I can use the Spring Initializr to build a Maven / Java project with Spring Boot 1.5.10, and the Dependencies of Web, JPA, and MySQL.

I put these lines in `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TEST

spring.datasource.username=jdbc

spring.datasource.password=jdbc
```

from the command line, I enter:

`mvn spring-boot:run`

and the (empty) project builds and runs fine.

If I do the same with Spring Boot 2.0.0, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project demo200: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.pageableCustomizer: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration] from ClassLoader [java.net.URLClassLoader@50815d80]: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper -> [Help 1]
```

If I add:

```
    <jackson.version>2.9.3</jackson.version>
```

to the `pom.xml`, it builds OK.

Is ObjectMapper missing from Jackson, 2.9.4 or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you generate a new project using the initializer and picking boot 2.0 or updated the dependency on your pom?

Comment: This is a new project, generated on the website, downloaded as a zip file, with boot 2.0.0 selected, and Maven run from the command line. I get the same result if I use Spring Tool Suite. If I update the <properties> in pom.xml to show the 2.9.3 version of jackson (rather than the 2.9.4 that is used by default), it builds OK.

Comment: I just did one with that exact stack but using gradle and It works ok. I think maven's dependency resolution is poorly configured in the pom.

Comment: Indeed, I got a bad Jackson 2.9.4 from the Maven Repository, and it was darned hard to get rid of it! In particular, nothing in STS or "mvn clean install -U" from the command line would shake it loose. Finally, I deleted ".m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.4" and it re-downloaded a correct version. Thanks!